# cannot send post request to my API controller with HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api

I am working on communication between API <-> webAPP via HttpClient.

This is my API controller:

```
        [HttpPut, Route("voipport/{newPort}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutVoipPort(int newPort)
    {
        try
        {
            await _repository.ChangePort(newPort);
            await _repository.AddNewRecord("PutVoipPort", "Success");
            return Ok();
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            return BadRequest(exception.Message);
        }

    }
```

this is fired from website with this:

```
        public async Task VOIPChangePort(int newPort)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newPort);
        var data = new StringContent(json,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
        var result = await _httpClient.PutAsync("voipport/{newPort}", data);
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

and this is the result:

```
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2022 18:15:08 GMT
  Server: Kestrel
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
}}
```

I dont know why i cannot call my controller method.

##UPDATE
this is solution

```
public async Task VOIPChangePort(int newPort)
{
    var result = await _httpClient.PutAsync($"voipport/{newPort}", null);
    result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

Comment: Don't pass any JSON. `newPort` seems to be part of the route and not the body. You're calling "voipport/{newPort}" when you should be templating that string with the actual `int` newPort, like this: `voipport/65000`.

Comment: Ok, you helped me. Answer this question. I found solution with your help! :)

Comment: At first I saw your 405 and was about to let you know about Put vs Post :). You're quick!

Comment: Yes i found that too right after i post this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newPort` seems to be part of the route and not the body. Don't pass any JSON.

You're calling `voipport/{newPort}` when you should be templating that string with the actual int newPort, like this: `voipport/65000`.

Comment: Thanks to you i found solution fast.